# Python sendmail() delivering after 12 hour delay

Tags: python, email, sendmail, delay

I'm trying to avoid checking my email all the time, so I download all of my email once every 4 hours. I have a cron job that fetches unread messages from a Gmail account and then sends them to an account that I check.

Recently however messages have been showing up inconsistently, sometimes with over a day's delay. All messages get sent correctly, but the delay is bizarre.

Here's my code:

```
imap_domain = "imap.gmail.com"
imap_port = 993
imap_username =  'remotegmailaccount@gmail.com'
imap_password = 'mypassword'

#smtp settings
smtp_domain = "mail.kburke.org"
smtp_port = 2626
smtp_username = "emailaddress@kburke.org"
smtp_password = "mypassword"

recipient = ['emailaddressIcheck@gmail.com']

imap_server = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_domain, imap_port)
imap_server.login(imap_username, imap_password)
imap_server.select('INBOX')
status, email_ids = imap_server.search(None, '(UNSEEN)')

server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_domain, smtp_port)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
server.login(smtp_username, smtp_password)

for e in email_ids[0].split(' '):
    if e is not '':
        try:
            raw_msg = imap_server.fetch(e, '(RFC822)')
            msg = email.message_from_string(raw_msg[1][0][1])

            #modify reply-to so we preserve email address
            if not msg['Reply-To']:
                msg['Reply-To'] = msg['From']

            result = server.sendmail(msg['From'], recipient, msg.as_string())
```

I think that it would be better to send from a Gmail account, but Gmail won't let you send email with a different recipient than the account owner. Do you know why emails are showing up with a delay, and what I can do to fix the problem? Thanks, Kevin

Comment: have you ever heard of a mail client? Thunderbird, Outlook, Evolution etc. all allow you to monitor several email accounts and receive notifications to your desktop.

Comment: Hi Rafe, My idea was to *avoid* checking my email, as I currently check it too often. I have better willpower if the download process is automated than if I can get my email any time I log in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at your mail server logs.  I bet you have lots of errors in there about GMail not accepting your email because (it looks like spam | that host has sent too many emails | other reason) and your mail server is doing it's usual "Hold on and try again later" routine.

It happened to me, rather suddenly one day for a similar type of use with GMail.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into the mail headers of your send mails. One is added for each mail server, together with a timestamp. Then you can see the culprit.

Comment: Once I find the culprit, what can I do to make it go faster?

Comment: Usually there are only two mail servers involved. The one you use to relay your mail, e.g. the one you have a mail account on, and the destination mail server, but depending on the destination there might theoretically be more hops. If your mail server is the culprit, use another provider to send the mails from. I have some google accounts I only use to send automated server mails, and I didn't see any problems yet.